# Time Capsule Connection Failed after update to Mavericks

Tags: time-machine, backup, time-capsule

After I updating OS X to Mavericks, Time Machine backup stopped to work on Time Capsule.

- I am connected on internet through Time Capsule without problems
- AirPort Utility indicators are green with no errors (as well as Time Capsule LED)
- Time Capsule name is displayed in Shared in Finder
- I didn't do any changes except for update to Mavericks

But Time Capsule connection fails:

- "Connection Failed" is displayed if I select TimeCapsule name in Finder
- If I click "Connect as…", error dialog says: "There was a problem connecting to the server …"
- If I click "Backup now" on Time Machine, it says: "Backup Failed: The backup disk … is not available."

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: When you click on the "Connect As..." button, are you prompted for your username and password? Are you able to connect to the Time Capsule in the Finder using Go -> Connect to Server (you may be able to enter the IP address of Kapsle - possibly 10.0.1.1?)

Answer (score 1):

In my case a serie of rabid and chaotic experiments with restarts and erasing a plist fixed the issue. Steps I did were:

- Disabled TM Backup
- Removed TimeCapsule from TM Backup Disk (this might not be necessary, you will not be able to add it again until it will start to work)
- Saving a screenshot of Exluded paths in TM Options (just for the case)
- Renamed /Library/Preferences/com.apple.TimeMachine.plist to *.bac
- Restarted Mac
- Restarted TimeMachine
- Removed /Library/Preferences/com.apple.TimeMachine.plist and renamed the old plist back
- Restarted Mac again
- Added a TimeCapsule back to TimeMachine Backup Disks

Hopefully it started to work. I don't know which of the steps were necessary and which just desperate.

Answer (score -1):

There is an epidemic hard drive failure problem associated with Mavericks.  Some drives (including my own Time Capsule) have been permanently damaged.  If that happens to your TC, you will get a constant amber light and the wifi will continue to work until the hard drive is restarted, because the wifi needs to access info on the disk to restart - something to consider before you unplug your TC or do a soft or hard reset.  If you have any Western Digital external hard drive applications on your computer, you may want to remove them (google Western Digital and Mavericks if that's a concern).  Good luck!

Comment: Hopefully not my case. After series of restarts and erasing plist it started to work properly.

Answer (score -1):

In airport utility: change routermode from off(bridge mode) to DHCP + nat.
After a reconnect, it works correctly.